# printf and new line

Tags: java, syntax

I was expecting the \n to cause the next statement to be printed on a new line but it doesn't...

is my syntax wrong?

```
writer.printf(" |\t\t\t | Tax Credits\t%010.2f |\n", taxCreds) ;
```

thanks

Baba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Java `printf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), the newline is a *conversion* character so you need to use `%n`:

> `%n`: Line separator, the result is the platform-specific line separator

Comment: Another option is to use - " System.getProperty("line.separator"); " This will also give you your platform newline.

Answer (score 1):

Use %n instead.  The API for PrintStream#printf will show this is so. 
Edit: actually this will direct you to the Formatter API where you will find that %n results in a system-specific new line.